# Derived state from props on React "truncate text" component

Tags: reactjs

I'm fairly new to React, just started using it about a week ago. I'm trying to develope a truncate text feature in a component, and got stuck in what seems to be a common newbie gotcha.

I have a patient info component, which shows people personal data such as name, birthdate, etc. The component is visually designed as card with a fixed width, and the person name needs to be truncated whenever its width exceeds that of the card:

[Original text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSQZA.png)
[Truncated text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QySDn.png)

(The "truncated" format is very specific and I cannot do it with CSS only)

I'm passing the person's name and surname via props from a parent component to a child PatientName component, which encapsulates and handles the truncate functionality. This is the code I'm using:

```
import './patient-name.css';

import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const TRUNCATED_MAX_SURNAME_CHARS = 10;
const TRUNCATED_SURNAME_ELLIPSIS = '...';

const TRUNCATED_MAX_NAME_CHARS = 1;
const TRUNCATED_NAME_ELLIPSIS = '.';

class PatientName extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { name: props.name, surname: props.surname };

    this.$element = React.createRef();
    this.$name = React.createRef();
  }

  isOverflowing() {
    const elementRightPos = this.$element.current.getBoundingClientRect().right;
    const nameRightPos = this.$name.current.getBoundingClientRect().right;

    return nameRightPos > elementRightPos;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.isOverflowing()) this.truncate();
  }

  truncate() {
    this.setState({
      name: `${this.props.name.substring(
        0,
        TRUNCATED_MAX_NAME_CHARS,
      )}${TRUNCATED_NAME_ELLIPSIS}`,
      surname: `${this.props.surname.substring(
        0,
        TRUNCATED_MAX_SURNAME_CHARS,
      )}${TRUNCATED_SURNAME_ELLIPSIS}`,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <h4 className="patient-name" ref={this.$element}>
        <span className="patient-surname">{this.state.surname}</span>
        &nbsp;
        <span ref={this.$name}>{this.state.name}</span>
      </h4>
    );
  }
}

PatientName.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string,
  surname: PropTypes.string,
};

export default PatientName;
```

This is working OK (I'm not worried about the truncate performance at the moment)... until I select another patient in the parent component. Then the patient name does not change, and it still shows the previous name that I passed via props.

I understand that the problem is deriving state from props, and that the constructor gets called only once and that the state never refreshes afterwards, etc, but... What would be the correct "React way" of doing this??

I'm coming from an Angular background I'm still trying to wrap my head around this.

Thanks!

PS: I'm using React 16.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your state if props change:

```
componenDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (prevProps.name !== this.props.name || prevProps.surname !== this.props.surname) {
    this.setState({name: this.props.name, surname: this.props.surname});
  }
  else if (prevState.name !== this.state.name || prevState.surname !== this.state.surname) {
    if (this.isOverflowing()) this.truncate();
  }
}
```

First `if` to update state and rerender with new untruncated `props` and get new measurements. The second `if` is for checking new measurements and truncating if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Since React 16.3+, there is a new component lifecycle which is a static method called [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) which return state and is triggered when the component is receiving props

So in your example, you can use it like this:

```js
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, state) {
   return ({
  ...state,
  name: `${nextProps.name.substring(
    0,
    TRUNCATED_MAX_NAME_CHARS,
  )}${TRUNCATED_NAME_ELLIPSIS}`,
  surname: `${nextProps.surname.substring(
    0,
    TRUNCATED_MAX_SURNAME_CHARS,
  )}${TRUNCATED_SURNAME_ELLIPSIS}`,
});
}
```